# ffmpeg mixing webm “Filter overlay has an unconnected output”

Tags: ffmpeg, mixing

I want to mix multiple webm
Below is my command
But ffmpeg error
“Filter overlay has an unconnected output”

```
ffmpeg -i 1596618603934.webm -i 1596618618345.webm  -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=1280x960[base];
[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=640*480[left];
[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=640*480[right];
[base][left]overlay=shortest=1[tmp1];
[tmp1][right] overlay=shortest=1:x=640[tmp2]" -c:v output.webm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you provide a label for the final output of a filtergraph, then it has to be mapped. So, either do that `-map '[tmp2]'` or omit the label.

```
ffmpeg -i 1596618603934.webm -i 1596618618345.webm  -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=1280x960[base];
[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=640*480[left];
[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=640*480[right];
[base][left]overlay=shortest=1[tmp1];
[tmp1][right] overlay=x=640" -c:v output.webm
```